# Python random.randrange producing everything but the step

Tags: python, python-3.x

When using this following code:

```
import random
sticks = 100
randomstep = random.randint(1, 6)
expertmarbles = random.randrange(1, sticks, 2**randomstep)
```

the output is producing everything excluding the step, so for example i would like this to output a random from these numbers: 2,4,8,16,32,64. However it will output everything but these numbers. Can anyone offer any advice, the reason i'm using variables here is because the amount of sticks will decrease.

Comment: Can you show examples of your actual and expected outputs?

Comment: So an actual output would be 97 but an expected one would would be any random one from this list: 2,4,8,16,32,64.

Comment: You can't use `step` for that. It can only do arithmetic progressions (1, 3, 5, 7...), not geometric (2, 4, 8, 16...).

Comment: Why not just use `expertmarbles = 2**randomstep`?

Comment: Okay thank you, it's for an ai type game where the amount of sticks the ai takes is to the power of 2 between 1 and a number and then deducts it from the amount left

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `random.randrange` you could use `random.choice` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice)):

```
import random
min_power = 1
max_power = 6
print(random.choice([2**i for i in range(min_power, max_power + 1)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
def myRand(pow_min,pow_max): 
    return 2**random.randint(pow_min,pow_max)
```

I would suggest you to use this instead of `random.choice`, which requires you to generate a list, which is unnecessary.